# Oracle restrict user to use USERS tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c

I have a schema 'TEST' that schema has own tablespace 'TEST'. But when I create index on USERS tablespace, it created. How can I restrict to use USERS tablespace in ORACLE database?

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "TEST"."INDEX1" ON "TEST"."TESTTABLE" ("TESTNO") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 
TABLESPACE "USERS"
```

It success, I want TEST user can't create any object on USERS tablespace. It has own TEST tablespace. Is there any configuration? Should user use TABLESPACE "TEST" instead of TABLESPACE "USERS" ?

Comment: I presume by "schema 'TEST' that schema has own tablespace 'TEST'" that you mean the default tablespace of 'TEST' is 'TEST'.

Comment: Yes. but my collagues said there are some indexes on USERS tablespaces. They don't want this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user `TEST` may have the `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE` privilege, or a quota defined on the `USERS` tablespace. To revoke them:

```
revoke unlimited tablespace from test;
alter user test quota 0 on users;
```

If the user had the `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE` privilege without any quota defined, you need to define a quota on the `TEST` tablespace, so the user can use it again after the above commands:

```
alter user test quota unlimited on test;
```

Comment: ok. thanks. Because of quota 0, data couldn't be inserted on tablespace USERS. Can't we revoke "create index ... tablespace 'USERS'" ?

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Balazs's answer and want to share a scenario here.

If you grant `RESOURCE` role to any user, the user gets `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE` privilege(Prior to 12c) which allows the user to create his/her objects on any tablespace.
You still can create index(You have `CREATE TABLE` priviliege) on the `USERS` tablespace after revoking `UNLIMITED TABLESPACE` privilege from `TEST` user BUT you can not insert data on it becuase you should have quota to do that.

Here is the demo:

```
SQL> create tablespace test_tbs datafile '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/test_tbs.dbf' size 50M;

Tablespace created.

SQL> create user test identified by test default tablespace test_tbs quota unlimited on test_tbs;

User created.



SQL> grant create session, resource to test;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn test/test
Connected.
SQL> create table testtable(testno number);

Table created.

SQL> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "TEST"."INDEX1" ON "TEST"."TESTTABLE" ("TESTNO") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 
TABLESPACE "USERS";  2    3    4    5    6  

Index created.

SQL> select * from session_privs;

PRIVILEGE
----------------------------------------
CREATE SESSION
UNLIMITED TABLESPACE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE CLUSTER
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE TRIGGER
CREATE TYPE
CREATE OPERATOR
CREATE INDEXTYPE

10 rows selected.

SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> revoke unlimited tablespace from test;

Revoke succeeded.

SQL> alter user test quota 0 on users;     

User altered.

SQL> conn test/test  
Connected.
SQL> drop index index1;

Index dropped.

SQL> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "TEST"."INDEX1" ON "TEST"."TESTTABLE" ("TESTNO") 
PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 
TABLESPACE "USERS";  2    3    4    5    6  

Index created.

SQL> insert into testtable values(1);
insert into testtable values(1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'TEST_TBS'


SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> alter user test quota unlimited on test_tbs;

User altered.

SQL> conn test/test
Connected.


SQL> insert into testtable values(1);
insert into testtable values(1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

Comment: thanks for demo.. I see Because of quota 0, it couldn't be inserted on index. Can't we revoke "create index ... tablespace 'USERS'" ?

Comment: @AhmetMelihBaşbuğ No, you can create index once you have create table privilege and appropriate quota on tablespace.